# Detect foreground application when in immersive mode

Tags: tasker, automation, immersive-mode

There are several  applications able to force the so called immersive ("full screen") mode. (Power Toggles being one of them)

My problem is that, in that configuration, Tasker and similar applications seem to be unable to detect which is the foreground running application: profiles based on that kind of state doesn't trigger until full screen mode is toggled off.

I'm looking for an alternate way to detect the foreground app (Tasker Plugin would be fine) which doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: Any other example of an app which can force immersive mode? Which ROM and Android version are you running?

Comment: There are many other applications, simply seacrh for "immersive mode" or "full screen" on the play store (I only mentioned the two I've tested)
And I'm running Android 5.1 on MotoX 2014

Comment: Here's the other application I'm currently using : (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.immersivemode).